# Is there any alternative way to achieve the benefit that we get with Azure CDN with multiple origin groups?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

We have created two API Management instances and they both are added to different origin groups on a CDN Endpoint and rules are defined to redirect requests to origin groups based on URL path.

For e.g. Request URL with path /**apim1** to Origin group1

```
  <custom-domain>/apim1 -> CDN Endpoint -> Origin group1 -> APIM1 Origin
```

For e.g. Request URL with path /**apim2** to Origin group2

```
   <custom-domain>/apim2 -> CDN Endpoint -> Origin group2 -> APIM2 Origin
```

This works fine , **but we are facing some issues in automating the resource creation using terraform, Looks like currently terraform does not support Origin groups**.

So looking for alternate options in Azure to achieve this. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at using Azure Front Door? depending on what you are trying to do this might anyway be more feasible

Comment: @silent yes it provides the routing features , but Azure front door is a load balancer service, Is it possible to disable load balancing and just use it for path based routing?.

Comment: yes, you can do that as well

Comment: you'll just create one backend group per APIM and only have one backend (=origin) per group. Then multiple routes

Comment: @silet  Okay , Let me try that , will post the updates here ,Thanks for you inputs